# How can I parse XML, changea a value, and write it back out on MacOS terminal?

Tags: xml, macos, bash

Preface: I'm not an iOS or Mac dev or user.

Want: I'd like to create a script (`.sh`, etc) that will

1. Open an XML file
2. Read out a value in a particular element
3. Augment the value
4. Write it back to the same element
5. Save the XML file (back to itself)

I've done a few searches but there doesn't seem to be any solutions posted (that I've found) which do this with OS-provided tools/toolkits. I need to *not* rely on external toolkits or, if absolutely necessary, be able to install whatever toolkit I need from the terminal or as part of the shell script's execution.

Why do I want to do this? We're building a cross-platform Cordova application which uses `config.xml` to specify the things that go in to each platform's "app manifest" files (ie: `.plist` for iOS apps) and we want to increment/change the version stored in this config file during the CI build process.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a config.xml line like this:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" />
```

And assume you want to change spec from 1 to 1.1 and origin from * to localhost. You can do it like this:

```
sed -i -e 's,<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />,<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1" />,' -e 's,<access origin="\*" />,<access origin="localhost" />,' config.xml
```

Note that I used commas instead of / as delimiters in order to allow literal /s inside the expression, and that the whole expression is wrapped in single-quotes, meaning that you would have to do it a little differently if you want to match any single quotes in the config.xml, and that I had to escape the * (\*). You would also need to put a \ before a . or a [. Best read up on sed http://www.funtoo.org/Sed_by_Example,_Part_2 and test the script thoroughly.

If each find/replace you want to do spans multiple lines, things get trickier.

A more involved but less brittle option would be to actually parse the xml. You could install an xml parser package and use it in a bash script. You could make a perl script that uses a perl module that parses xml. Or, since it's a cordova project, you likely have node.js installed, and you could write a node script which uses an npm module that parses xml.